# Selenium Webdriver exception at startup

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run selenium webdriver for the first time. My platform is python2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. The script below launches a Firefox instance, pauses 30 seconds or so, and then exits.

Both firefox and selenium were installed using `apt-get`.

The relevant versions appear to be:

- firefox: 31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
- python-selenium: 2.25.0-0ubuntu1

```
$ cat x.py 
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from selenium import webdriver
try: driver = webdriver.Firefox()
except Exception as e: print e.msg
$ python x.py 
Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmp6RP7Q9 Firefox output: 
(process:1705): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:1705): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:1705): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:1705): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:1705): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
1407121545974   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1407121545977   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1407121545980   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1407121546015   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1407121546027   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1407121546035   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1407121546038   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi

$
```

What must I do to run the Firefox webdriver on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of selenium-webdriver in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS appears to be out of date. Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge python-selenium
$ sudo pip install selenium
```